# Homology of the simplicial complex obtained from an octahedron by removing 4 faces.

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplex, simplicial-stuff

Suppose you have the surface of an octahedron and you remove 4 of the eight faces as follows:

If you remove one face then you don't remove all the adyacent faces and so on.

You can look at this as a simpicial complex so you should be able to calculate it's simpicial homology, but that's where I'm stuck.

I suspect it has the same or similar homology as a two torus but I´m not sure.

http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/polyhedra/platonic/octahedron.html

For example, in the image I linked, you would remove the red and blue faces (or the yellow and green) and the two faces which would be opposite to the blue and red faces.

Comment: If you remove the red and blue faces, you obtain a space which is equivalent to a $2$-sphere with two holes, and this is equivalent, in turn, to a $1$-sphere.

Comment: yes, but you remove not only the red and blue faces but also the faces that are opposite to them

Comment: Is this an accurate rephrasing? "Remove *every other face* (that is, two of the four faces) that meets at a vertex, never removing adjacent faces". I have in mind [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahemihexahedron) but with only the red faces, none of the (square) yellow ones.

Comment: yes indeed, only the red faces, but behind the yellow plane you have two other "red" faces, which are not adyacent to the two visible red faces

Answer (score 0):

You could write down what the faces of the simplicial complex are and the compute boundary maps and homology. This is a useful exercise if you are new to simplicial topology.

Or you could just look at that picture and imagine poking out the red and blue faces. Both the top and bottom half are homotopic to a circle. You get that $\tilde{H}_1$ has dimension 2, and all other reduced homologies vanish.

Comment: If you remove *two* opposite faces, you obtain a twice punctured sphere, and this is homotopic to a circle, which has $H_1$ the integers.

Comment: He is not removing 2 faces though. He is removing 4.

Comment: In his picture in the link, the top face opposite the visible red face is also removed. Similarly, the bottom face opposite the blue.  Here I mean opposite within the hemisphere.

Comment: indeed I am removing 4 faces, of which only two are visible in the picture